# Error while taking input invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1 2 3'

Tags: python-3.x, input

```
def kad(l):
    max_c=max_g=l[0]
    for i in range(0,len(l)):
        max_c=max(l[i],l[i]+max_c)

        if(max_c>max_g):

            max_g=max_c

    print(max_c)
    return max_g

t=int(input("test case")) ## TEST CASES
for k in range (0,t):
    n=int(input(" num"))    # TOTAL NUMBERS IN EACH TEST CASE
    l=[float(int(input())) for i in range(0,n)]
    if(len(l)>0):
        kad(l)

    print(l)
```

**Error Message**

```
File "/home/dc97fc38c3d1e4a695c9d3550e8af5c1.py", line 16, in <module>
l=[float(int(input())) for i in range(0,n)]
File "/home/dc97fc38c3d1e4a695c9d3550e8af5c1.py", line 16, in <listcomp>
l=[float(int(input())) for i in range(0,n)]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1 2 3'
```

Even the code is working fine in the local editor(Jupyter notebook) but displays the error in the online editor.

Comment: it's not very clear for users about what values they need to input, `t` is one number, `n` is one number, and then `l` is `n` times a number, not a list of `n` numbers. If you want to input a list, then you should `split` a unique input before the comprehension list

Comment: for reference **solution link:** https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/NVBsN6xwVj  ** problem link:**  https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/kadanes-algorithm/0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No idea what your function tries to do - for empty lists it gives an error(which you guard against) , for only positive inputs it is a convoluted way of summing up all numbers, adding the first value twice.

It looks like a mangled solutions to some hackerrank'isc site.

You should fix your input like this:

```
for _ in range(int(input("test case"))): ## TEST CASES
    _ = input() # TOTAL NUMBERS IN EACH TEST CASE
    # the number of numbers does not matter - you get it as len(l) if needed
    l = list(map(float,input().strip().split())) # split the input and parse it to floats
               #  ^^^ change to int if you only handle int's - your error suggest so
    if(len(l)>0):
        kad(l)
```

Comment: for reference **solution link:** [link](https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/NVBsN6xwVj)   problem link:[link](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/kadanes-algorithm/0)

Comment: @Amit  - you might also want to fix this line: `for i in range(0,len(l)):` to `for i in range(1,len(l)):` inside `def kad(l):`